# Using React, NodeJS, and Postgres: Having trouble being able to delete without getting a 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD app that posts a list of things to the Postgres database. I'm having trouble being able to delete from the app as I keep getting 404 errors. I think that I'm doing something is wrong on the backend as I can't even delete with Postman.

deletion.js // deletion router

```
router.delete('/',(req,res)=>{
    var item = req.params.index;
    console.log(`req.params.index is ${req.params.index}`)


    let deletion = `DELETE FROM tnotesapi1.tearecords
       WHERE primary_key = ${item}`


    client.query(deletion, (res,err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.error(`Record Query error, ${err.stack}`)

        }else{
            console.log('Item has been deleted from dB')
            res.send()
        }
    })


})
```

the router handler for the server

```
app.delete('/api/delete/:index',deleteRouter)
```

Also, how do I use the axios on the frontend?

```
tearecord.delete(`delete/`,{params:index})
        .then(res => {
            console.log();
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only one reason why you get `404 ERROR` is because your route not found.

**Why your route not Found?** It's because in your handler: `server.js` or `app.js`, you're set a method delete like this:

```
app.delete('/api/delete/:index',deleteRouter)
```

You should not to do that, because you ever set `delete` method in the `deletion.js`. So, you only need to make something like this:

```
app.use('/api/delete/:index',deleteRouter)
```

**The code above  only for example**. If that confuses you, you can see the full code below.

‍  You can do it like this code below :

**deletion.js**

```js
router.delete('/:index',(req,res)=>{
    var item = req.params.index;
    console.log(`req.params.index is ${req.params.index}`)


    let deletion = `DELETE FROM tnotesapi1.tearecords
       WHERE primary_key = ${item}`


    client.query(deletion, (res,err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.error(`Record Query error, ${err.stack}`)

        }else{
            console.log('Item has been deleted from dB')
            res.send()
        }
    })
})
```

In the code above , you have to add a `params`. Because you're using `index`,  than you have to add `index` as `params`.

**server/app.js**

```js
app.use('/api/delete', deleteRouter)
```

Now, in your `server` or `app` handler, **you don't have** to using `delete` again. Because you use it in your `deletion.js`.

**Frontend:** using `axios`

```js
// change with your endpoint
const endPoint = 'http://localhost:3000/api/delete/' + index;
axios.delete(endpoint)
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
  }).catch(ex => {
    console.log(ex.data);
  })
```

**Updated:** Using Fetch.

If you're using *React*, then you can use `fetch` in there, without using `axios`.

You can use an example code below:

```js
async handleDelete(index) {
  try {
    // change the endpoint with yours
    const endpoint =  'http://localhost:3000/api/delete/' + index;
    const result = await fetch( endpoint, { method: 'DELETE' });
    const json = await result.json();
    console.log(json);
    // do some stuff here: set state or some stuff you want
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
}
```

The code above  **an example**, how to send `delete` request to your backend using `fetch` in react.

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I helped clear up my problems.

Answer (score 0):

in your **axios** request pass index directly as param with api call

```
tearecord.delete(`/api/delete/${index}`)  // pass your index directly 
  .then(res => {
            console.log();
        })
```

**Backend :**

```
router.delete('/api/delete/:index',(req,res)=>{ // put here index as params in backend 
    var item = req.params.index;
```